# Rack::File is deprecated, please use Rack::Files instead - new Ruby on Rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rack, hix-on-rails

When I create new Ruby on Rails (6.0.2.1) project with [Hix on Rails Application Template](https://hixonrails.com/getting-started), I get the following error:

> `Rack::File` is deprecated, please use `Rack::Files`

What exactly causes it?

Comment: I created a rails 5.1 project an hour ago I also get same output

Comment: If you'll be able to track an exact reason why, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this issue by updating the gem rack:

```
bundle update rack
```

Answer (score 1):

Found this discussion in the Rack repo. It's just a warning.

https://github.com/rack/rack/commit/f80e65d5dde251ee446e4c0bd038f8bc4ec30314